# Why does mysql ceil datetime strings?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I'm having a problem when searching a datetime column with a string.

I'm using codeigniters insert_batch, but I'm sure it's the same if I use insert. This is an example of the data I'm inserting:

```
$valor_log_proceso = array(
        'id_interno' => 21656,
        'proceso_id' => 1,
        'fecha_inicio' => '2015-12-02T09:04:59.884',
        'fecha_fin' => '2015-12-02T09:20:10.884',
        'equipo' => "EQUIPOPC",
        'usuario_id' => 2,
        'log_envio_id' => 10
    );
```

In the mysql db 'fecha_inicio' and 'fecha_fin' are `datetime` colmuns.
'fecha_inicio' and 'fecha_fin' values in every single $valor_log_proceso array are strings retrieved from a request.

When I try to look for that data with a get_where

```
$valor_log_proceso = array(
        'id_interno' => 21656,
        'proceso_id' => 1,
        'fecha_inicio' => '2015-12-02T09:04:59.884',
        'fecha_fin' => '2015-12-02T09:20:10.884',
        'equipo' => "EQUIPOPC",
        'usuario_id' => 2
    );
$result = $this->db->get_where($table_name, $valor_log_proceso)->result_array();
```

`$result` is an empty array.

Then I check the database and see that the dates where truncated/ceiled to:

```
fecha_inicio: 2015-12-02 09:05:00
fecha_fin: 2015-12-02 09:20:11
```

So the question is why does that happen?
How can I search correctly for rows in the table?

Comment: What is the column type set to? Integer, varchar?

Comment: the type of the colums in mysql is just `datetime`

Comment: I have never seen a datetime column holding a value like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that a DATETIME column can only have this pattern of data. As you see, it is stripping out the 'T' as well.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

`The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'`

In order to create the query correctly, you will have to change your array to match the same pattern...

```
    'fecha_inicio' => '2015-12-02 09:04:59',
    'fecha_fin'    => '2015-12-02 09:20:10',
```

**ADDITION**

Here is a function to manipulate the current format to the needed format

```
function format($x){
    $x = preg_replace('/[T]/', ' ', $x);
    $y = explode(".", $x);
    return $y[0];
}

$x = format('2015-12-02T09:04:59.884');

echo $x;  // Prints 2015-12-02 09:04:59
```

Comment: a solution to his problem? perhaps store in a var char field and convert do a date_format when selecting?

Comment: I see, thanks, do you have any idea how could I correctly convert the `string '2015-12-02T09:04:59.884'` into the datetime value that would be inserted in the database?

Comment: I think you can use DATE_FORMAT but checkout the functions on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Seeing that the miliseconds may not provide value to the date, I guess I'll have to manipulate the dates strings, that is truncate the milliseconds before inserting them.

Comment: @Jedabero Added a function to convert the current format to the required format